# Swift array loop once, write many

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Consider the following silly, simple example:

```
let arr = ["hey", "ho"]
let doubled = arr.map {$0 + $0}
let capitalized = arr.map {$0.capitalizedString}
```

As you can see, I'm processing the same initial array in multiple ways in order to end up with multiple processed arrays.

Now imagine that `arr` is very long and that I have many such processes generating many final arrays. I don't like the above code because we are looping multiple times, once for each `map` call. I'd prefer to loop just once.

Now, obviously we could handle this by brute force, i.e. by starting with multiple mutable arrays and writing into all of them on each iteration:

```
let arr = ["hey", "ho"]
var doubled = [String]()
var capitalized = [String]()
for s in arr {
    doubled.append(s + s)
    capitalized.append(s.capitalizedString)
}
```

Fine. But now we don't get the joy of using `map`. So my question is: is there a better, Swiftier way? In a hazy way I imagine myself using `map`, or something like `map`, to generate something like a tuple and magically splitting that tuple out into all resulting arrays as we iterate, as if I could say something like this (pseudocode, don't try this at home):

```
let arr = ["hey", "ho"]
let (doubled, capitalized) = arr.map { /* ???? */ }
```

If I were designing my own language, I might even permit a kind of splatting by assignment into a pseudo-array of lvalues:

```
let arr = ["hey", "ho"]
let [doubled, capitalized] = arr.map { /* ???? */ }
```

No big deal if it can't be done, but it would be fun to be able to talk this way.

Comment: So is the goal here simply a terser syntax? Your original code, with 2 `map` calls, should be marginally less efficient than looping once but has advantage of being more parallelizable in your case of multiple processes, which seems desirable.

Comment: @JackWu Oh yes, it's purely a syntactic dream. I don't even really know if there's anything particularly inefficient about what I'm doing. I'm not optimizing prematurely, just staring at my code and pondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a function, `multimap`, that takes a collection of transformations, and applies each one, returning them as an array of arrays:

```
// yay protocol extensions
extension SequenceType {
    // looks like T->U works OK as a constraint
    func multimap
      <U, C: CollectionType 
       where C.Generator.Element == Generator.Element->U>
    (transformations: C) -> [[U]] {
        return transformations.map {
            self.map($0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
let arr = ["hey", "ho"]

let double: String->String = { $0 + $0 }
let uppercase: String->String = { $0.uppercaseString }

arr.multimap([double, uppercase])
// returns [["heyhey", "hoho"], ["HEY", "HO"]]
```

Or it might be quite nice in variadic form:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func multimap<U>(transformations: (Generator.Element->U)...) -> [[U]] {
        return self.multimap(transformations)
    }
}

arr.multimap({ $0 + $0 }, { $0.uppercaseString })
```

Edit: if you want separate variables, I think the best you can do is a `destructure` function (which you have to declare n times for each n-tuple unfortunately):

```
// I don't think this can't be expressed as a protocol extension quite yet
func destructure<C: CollectionType>(source: C) -> (C.Generator.Element,C.Generator.Element) {
    precondition(source.count == 2)
    return (source[source.startIndex],source[source.startIndex.successor()])
}

// and, since it's a function, let's declare pipe forward
// to make it easier to call
infix operator |> { }
func |> <T,U>(lhs: T, rhs: T->U) -> U {
    return rhs(lhs)
}
```

And then you can declare the variables like this:

```
let (doubled,uppercased)
    = arr.multimap({ $0 + $0 }, { $0.uppercaseString }) |> destructure
```

Yes this is a teensy bit inefficient because you have to build the array then rip it apart – but that’s really not going to be material, since the arrays are copy-on-write and we’re talking about a small number of them in the outer array.

edit: an excuse to use the new `guard` statement:

```
func destructure<C: Sliceable where C.SubSlice.Generator.Element == C.Generator.Element>(source: C) -> (C.Generator.Element,C.Generator.Element) {
    guard let one = source.first else { fatalError("empty source") }
    guard let two = dropFirst(source).first else { fatalError("insufficient elements") }

    return (one,two)
}
```

Comment: Alas, I really need to end up with separate multiple one-dimensional arrays. So I would still need another loop to split the array of arrays out into those separate arrays. Otherwise I'd have done the same thing less neatly using old-fashioned `map`...

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah you’re right you need splatting. Maybe Swift 3.0 will have a variadic generic placeholder syntax, that’s what’s missing I think (e.g. would allow you to write a generic array destructure into tuples, generic `zip` etc)

Comment: I'm confused (not unusual). Is this going to work no matter how many closures and ultimate 1-d array variables are involved? (In real life, there are more like ten of them.) And no matter what the closures produce? (In real life, some target final arrays are of string, others are of Int, and so on.)

Comment: So, `multimap` will work with any number of closures.  `destructure` you have to overload n times for every n-tuple you might want to create… see https://github.com/typelift/Swiftz/blob/master/Swiftz/Curry.swift as an example of this madness.  But once you do this, it will auto-deduce which overload to use based on the left-hand of the assignment.

Comment: Forgot to ask, what's `precondition`? I haven't come across it in my WWDC  video watching yet.

Comment: It's like assert but it gets checked in release builds too. Unless you build -Ounchecked

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with your suggestion of tuple?

```
let arr = ["hey", "ho"]

let  mapped = arr.map {e in
  return (e + e, e.capitalizedString)
}
```

Comment: Because then I need to split the tuple. I need separate 1-d arrays at the end. Imagine a river dividing into 5 branches: I'm trying to flow my original array into 5 arrays at once. :)

Comment: but then you get to have more map joy let doubles = mapped.map { $0.0 } :)

Comment: But then we loop twice (each `map` is a loop). Goal was: loop only once - remember? :)

Comment: Your suggestion is not without merit, but the second loop to split out the tuples is kind of messy, and it's more or less impossible to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, we process 'capitalized' array while we map the 'doubled' array:

```
let arr = ["hey", "ho"]

var capitalized = [String]()
let doubled = arr.map {(var myString) -> String in
    capitalized.append(myString.capitalizedString)
    return myString + myString
} 

//doubled ["heyhey", "hoho"]
//capitalized: ["Hey", "Ho"]
```

Comment: While this works, it is quite bad and adds side-effects to the functional `map`

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with that, I would choose the solution of @Airspeed Velocity